# Java versions on win 7

Tags: java, windows-7

I have JDK 8 with update 5 installed on my Windows 7 machine. I went to a Java version verification site, which asks me to download a version 7 update 60 of a plugin. I am just confused, because JDK 8 should be picked up by the browser and it's not. I have tried both Chrome and IE . Did I miss anything?

Comment: Depends on the browser.  Chrome is blocking NPAPI plugins such as Java in its browser, and most other browsers have it explicitly blacklisted due to security holes.  The only one I know of that *might* work would be Firefox, but again, it depends on what browser you're using and its version.

Comment: I think this question can be answered better on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Why is Java 8 not available on java.com?

Java 8 is the latest release for Java that contains new features, enhancements and bug fixes to improve efficiency to develop and run Java programs.

The new release of Java is first made available to developers to ensure no major problems are found before we make it available on the java.com website for end users to download. If you are interested in trying Java 8 it can be downloaded from Oracle.com.

Read more at:

See http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java8.xml